# Multiple Domains on one Shared Server, need to use mod_rewrite to find paths to content

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns

I have 3 different domains, www.example.com, www.mywebsite.com, www.domain.com. In my server, I have 3 folders, www/example, www/mywebsite, www/domain. I want each URL to point to each respective folder, and I want all requests to the different URLs to find the content in its own folder. For example, when a user types www.example.com/home.php, I want it to find the file www/example/home.php, but without having the URL redirect to www.example.com/example/home.php (I don't want the directory names to be visible).

The problem is that I am on a shared server, and therefore I cannot edit the conf files to instill VirtualHosts or change DocumentRoots. So I need a method that involves an htaccess file.

Essentially, I need an htaccess file in the root directory, www/.htaccess, which tells the server that when a request is made to www.example.com, return the contents in www/example folder, and so on for my other domains.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} example1\.com$
ReqriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/example1.com/$1

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} example2\.com$
ReqriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/example2.com/$1
```